# how to query data in a json file if exists add extra field with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

hi guys i  have been researching for a while but i could not find any solutions i would like to check my datas on json file if a value exists i would like to extra field is there any way to do this thanks

FOR EXAMPLE THIS IS MY JSON FILE

```
[
{
    "image": "https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/30/d0/30d0cedf71114d5bb6295ad7dd179aee32ab7bc7.jpg],origin[dam],category[men_jacketscoats_jackets],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[y],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]",
    "title": "Pamuklu Kısa Ceket",
    "link": "https://www2.hm.com/tr_tr/productpage.0735833001.html",
    "oldprice": "1.099,00 ",
    "newprice": "379,00 "
},
{
    "image": "https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/d8/6d/d86d30f768adc021e943ce5dcacc7f8243c19ea7.jpg],origin[dam],category[men_shoes_sneakers],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[y],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/main]",
    "title": "Spor Ayakkabı",
    "link": "https://www2.hm.com/tr_tr/productpage.0522678003.html",
    "oldprice": "299,00 ",
    "newprice": "119,00 "
}
```

]

I WOULD LIKE TO CHECK IF {"tittle"=="ceket"}
add category field like this

```
[
{
    "image": "https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/30/d0/30d0cedf71114d5bb6295ad7dd179aee32ab7bc7.jpg],origin[dam],category[men_jacketscoats_jackets],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[y],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]",
    "title": "Pamuklu Kısa Ceket",
    "link": "https://www2.hm.com/tr_tr/productpage.0735833001.html",
    "oldprice": "1.099,00 ",
    "newprice": "379,00 ",
    "category": "Ceket"

},
{
    "image": "https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/d8/6d/d86d30f768adc021e943ce5dcacc7f8243c19ea7.jpg],origin[dam],category[men_shoes_sneakers],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[y],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/main]",
    "title": "Spor Ayakkabı",
    "link": "https://www2.hm.com/tr_tr/productpage.0522678003.html",
    "oldprice": "299,00 ",
    "newprice": "119,00 "
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat your JSON input just like a list of Python dictionaries once parsed. Assign your JSON input to a variable and then you can do something like the code below.

First, let's parse your input file using the json module:

```
import json

jsonInput = """[{
    "image": "https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/30/d0/30d0cedf71114d5bb6295ad7dd179aee32ab7bc7.jpg],origin[dam],category[men_jacketscoats_jackets],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[y],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]",
    "title": "Pamuklu Kısa Ceket",
    "link": "https://www2.hm.com/tr_tr/productpage.0735833001.html",
    "oldprice": "1.099,00 ",
    "newprice": "379,00 "
},
{
    "image": "https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/d8/6d/d86d30f768adc021e943ce5dcacc7f8243c19ea7.jpg],origin[dam],category[men_shoes_sneakers],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[y],hmver[2]&call=url[file:/product/main]",
    "title": "Spor Ayakkabı",
    "link": "https://www2.hm.com/tr_tr/productpage.0522678003.html",
    "oldprice": "299,00 ",
    "newprice": "119,00 "
}]"""

jsonInput = json.loads(jsonInput)
```

Then let's loop through the parsed JSON, query for "Ceket" and add an extra field if found:

```
n=0
### Loop through the input (Json just a list of dicts)
for i in jsonInput:
    ### Loop through the values within the dict
    for value in i.values():
        ### Check if string is there
        if "Ceket" in value:
            ### If so grab the list item number
            listItem = n
    n += 1 # Increment the list item number with each loop

jsonInput[listItem]["category"] = "Ceket" # Add a new dictionary 'key':value to the list item
print(jsonInput)
```

If you need to output JSON you can use the json module - check out https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp